# WEB SCRAPING con PYTHON

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I need to be able to download the data that is in the attached link, however I cannot assign it to a variable and display it as a dataframe. Attached part of the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url ='https://gee.bccr.fi.cr/IndicadoresEconomicos/Cuadros/frmConsultaTCVentanilla.aspx'

r = requests.get(url)
htmld_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmld_doc,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.title)
print(soup.table('Resultado de la consulta'))
table_body=soup.find('tbody')
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Esteban, could you please clarify what is meant by "I cannot assign it to a variable and display it as a dataframe?" Are you getting an error? If so, what's the message?

Comment: Hi Brian, The drawback is that I have not been able to extract the table that is in the attached link, I do not know which part of the html parameter I should subtract and to do this modify my code.
If possible, help me modify the code to obtain the information from the table in the link. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Esteban Why can't you export the data in excel file which is available on the website itself. Same table data it is giving you in excel file.If you want to automate the downloading of excel from website you can do it using Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to load the HTML table to pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://gee.bccr.fi.cr/IndicadoresEconomicos/Cuadros/frmConsultaTCVentanilla.aspx'
content = requests.get(url).text

df = pd.read_html(content)[2]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.loc[1:, :]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
0        Tipo de Entidad                                 Entidad Autorizada Compra  Venta Diferencial Cambiario   Última Actualización
1        Bancos públicos                                Banco de Costa Rica  58800  60100                  1300  15/09/2020 01:15 p.m.
2                    NaN                       Banco Nacional de Costa Rica  58800  60100                  1300  15/09/2020 03:15 p.m.
3                    NaN              Banco Popular y de Desarrollo Comunal  58700  60000                  1300  11/09/2020 12:57 p.m.
4        Bancos privados                            Banco BAC San José S.A.  58900  60200                  1300  15/09/2020 01:13 p.m.
5                    NaN                                     Banco BCT S.A.  58900  60300                  1400  15/09/2020 02:10 p.m.
6                    NaN                    Banco Cathay de Costa Rica S.A.  58800  60300                  1500  10/09/2020 12:09 p.m.
7                    NaN                                          Banco CMB  58100  60300                  2200  11/09/2020 09:40 a.m.
8                    NaN                  Banco Davivienda (Costa Rica) S.A  58400  60400                  2000  15/09/2020 01:09 p.m.
9                    NaN                    Banco General (Costa Rica) S.A.  58600  60100                  1500  16/09/2020 01:08 a.m.
10                   NaN                                 Banco Improsa S.A.  58700  60300                  1600  10/09/2020 12:02 p.m.
11                   NaN                                  Banco Lafise S.A.  58700  60300                  1600  15/09/2020 08:11 a.m.
12                   NaN                               Banco Promérica S.A.  58700  60195                  1495  15/09/2020 05:26 p.m.
13                   NaN                Banco Scotiabank de Costa Rica S.A.  58400  60200                  1800  15/09/2020 02:23 p.m.
14                   NaN                       Prival Bank (Costa Rica) S.A  58700  60200                  1500  11/09/2020 08:13 a.m.
15           Financieras                              Financiera Cafsa S.A.  58800  60200                  1400  15/09/2020 08:44 p.m.
16                   NaN                             Financiera Comeca S.A.  58600  60300                  1700  15/09/2020 01:53 p.m.
17                   NaN                            Financiera Desyfin S.A.  58900  60200                  1300  11/09/2020 11:03 a.m.
18                   NaN                                Financiera Gente SA  59000  60000                  1000  16/09/2020 12:18 a.m.
19  Mutuales de Vivienda  Grupo Mutual Alajuela - La Vivienda de Ahorro ...  58900  60100                  1200  15/09/2020 03:43 p.m.
20                   NaN                Mutual Cartago de Ahorro y Préstamo  58900  60200                  1300  15/09/2020 12:46 p.m.
21          Cooperativas                                Coope-ANDE N°1 R.L.  58600  60000                  1400  12/09/2020 08:30 a.m.
22                   NaN                          Cooperativa COOCIQUE R.L.  58800  60100                  1300  16/09/2020 12:29 a.m.
23                   NaN                      Cooperativa Coopealianza R.L.  58800  60100                  1300  11/09/2020 05:42 p.m.
24                   NaN                         Cooperativa CREDECOOP R.L.  58800  60100                  1300  15/09/2020 11:32 a.m.
25                   NaN  Cooperativa Nacional de Educadores R.L. (COOPE...  58700  60000                  1300  15/09/2020 10:41 a.m.
26                   NaN                        Cooperativa San Marcos R.L.  58800  60100                  1300  11/09/2020 11:39 a.m.
27                   NaN                               Coopeservidores R.L.  58900  60200                  1300  15/09/2020 03:22 p.m.
28       Casas de Cambio                     Casa de Cambio Global Exchange  51085  68222                 17137  16/09/2020 12:00 a.m.
29                   NaN                     Casa de Cambio Teledolar S. A.  58800  60800                  2000  16/09/2020 12:35 a.m.
30      Puestos de Bolsa                 BCT Valores, Puesto De Bolsa, S.A.  58900  60300                  1400  15/09/2020 02:20 p.m.
31                   NaN                   BN Valores S.A., Puesto de Bolsa  58600  60000                  1400  15/09/2020 08:21 a.m.
32                   NaN      Mercado Valores de Costa Rica Puesto de Bolsa  58500  60200                  1700  15/09/2020 10:46 a.m.
33                   NaN                                PB Inversiones SAMA  59200  60200                  1000  15/09/2020 11:35 a.m.
34                   NaN                   Popular Valores, Puesto de Bolsa  58700  60000                  1300  15/09/2020 08:29 a.m.
35                   NaN                                                NaN    NaN    NaN                   NaN                    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.